# Button in a row in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableListView with three levels.
In the adapter for the first level, I have the getGroupView which renders a TextView, and it works fine.

```
@Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             TextView tv = new TextView(context);
             tv.setText(mCountries.get(groupPosition).getName());
             tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
             tv.setPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);
             return tv;
        }
```

But now I wanted to take it to the next level.. just inflating an XML and have instead of just a TextView, a Button too; nevertheless, it doesn't work then, since it doesn't expand when I click on a row.
This is the adapted method, and of course, in the constructor, I initialize the inflater:

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.countries_row, null, false);
        mCountryName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.CountryTextView);
        mCountryName.setText(mCountries.get(groupPosition).getName());
        mCountryName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        mCountryName.setPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);
        mCountryExpandButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.CountryExpandButton);
        return v;
    }
```

`mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Can anybody please throw some light on why it doesn't work, and how to fix it?
It's really strange because it's just changing a TextView for a View..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way:

In the activity class:

```
public void expandGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    if(expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
        expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
    else
        expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
}
```

In the class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter:

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(acti);
    View rtnview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXX, null);
    TextView text=(TextView)rtnview.findViewById(R.id.tvinfo1);
    text.setText(groupArray.get(groupPosition));
    text.setTextColor(acti.getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
    text.setTextSize(EDEnv.EEfontSize+3);
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            acti.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        }
    });

    Button btn1=(Button)rtnview.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setId(groupPosition);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            acti.showDialog(1);
        }
    });

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = rtnview;
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

By this way you can expand the group item while has a button on the group item to do something else. There must be a better way to do this. But I don't have time to study on it.